# I'm trying to put numbers into a list and square and print them all

Tags: python, python-3.x

So, I'm trying to put numbers into a list and square and print them all.

This is what I have :

```
import math
ListNum = [2,4,6,8]
for item in ListNum:
    list(map(float, ListNum)
print(math.sqrt(ListNum))
```

but then I have this error:

> File "Main.py", line 5
>       print(math.sqrt(ListNum))
>           ^
>   SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Something with line 5 print. Any one that could help?

Comment: side note: squaring is not `math.sqrt`...

Comment: what is expected output mate ?

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
import math
ListNum = [2,4,6,8]
for item in ListNum:
    print (math.sqrt(item))
    print (item*item)
```

The difference is that here you are printing every item in the list and not the list itself.

The first line - `print (math.sqrt(item))` prints square root and the second -  `print (item*item)` prints the square.

Answer (score 0):

why not just create a list (using a list-comprehension) containing the result and then printing that (in whatever format)?

```
from math import sqrt

ListNum = [2,4,6,8]

ret = [sqrt(x) for x in ListNum]
print(ret)
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer the original question - SyntaxError is due to missing closing parenthesis on line 4 `list(map(float, ListNum)` should be `list(map(float, ListNum))`. Sometimes the error is on the previous line (line 4 in this case), not the one indicated in the traceback (in this case line 5).
The code will not deliver what you expect though. See the other answers for that.

Answer (score 0):

```
import math
ListNum = [2,4,6,8]
for item in ListNum:
    list(map(float, ListNum)  <--- you miss a parenthese
print(math.sqrt(ListNum))
```

And `math.sqrt` is calculating for square root:

```
>> help(math.sqrt)
sqrt(...)
    sqrt(x)

    Return the square root of x.
```

For squaring:

```
import math
ListNum = [2,4,6,8]
result = list(map(math.pow, ListNum, [2]*len(ListNum)))
```

For square root:

```
import math
ListNum = [2,4,6,8]
result = list(map(math.sqrt, ListNum))
```

Answer (score 0):

In the document of python3, which you can find the link at the bottom, math.sqrt() is described as "Return the square root of x". 
Since ListNum is actually a list, math.sqrt() will have trouble recognizing any types other than numbers.

And the'SyntaxError' comes from a missing ')' at the end of line 4.

The following code could work.

```
import math
ListNum = [2,4,6,8]
ListNum = list(map(math.sqrt,ListNum))
print (ListNum)
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html

Answer (score 0):

You can't take the square root of a list, and `ListNum` is a list.

If you want to take the *square root* (not square) of all numbers, you can map `math.sqrt` on to the list:

```
import math
ListNum = [2,4,6,8]
roots = list(map(math.sqrt, ListNum))
print(roots)
```

Note that there is no loop; the iteration is abstracted into `map`.

If you want to *square* the numbers, you need a squaring function:

```
def square(x) : return x * x
print(list(map(square, ListNum)))
```

or

```
print(list(map(lambda x: x* x, ListNum)))
```